# Why can I not browse my ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to view my ASP.NET web page but it only gets displayed if I am not connected to the internet. There is no proxy server.

The address I am using:

> http://localhost:50266/IWS/MyWorld.aspx

The message I receive:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the
>   webpage 
>          Most likely causes: You are not connected to the Internet.  The
>   website is encountering problems. 
>   There might be a typing error in the
>   address. 
>        What you can try: 
>        Diagnose Connection Problems
>
> More information
>
> This problem can be caused by a
>   variety of issues, including:
>
> Internet connectivity has been lost. 
>   The website is temporarily
>   unavailable.  The Domain Name Server
>   (DNS) is not reachable.  The Domain
>   Name Server (DNS) does not have a
>   listing for the website's domain.  If
>   this is an HTTPS (secure) address,
>   click Tools, click Internet Options,
>   click Advanced, and check to be sure
>   the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled
>   under the security section.
>
> For offline users
>
> You can still view subscribed feeds
>   and some recently viewed webpages. To
>   view subscribed feeds
>
> Click the Favorites Center button ,
>   click Feeds, and then click the feed
>   you want to view.
>
> To view recently visited webpages
>   (might not work on all pages)
>
> Click Tools , and then click Work
>   Offline.  Click the Favorites Center
>   button , click History, and then click
>   the page you want to view.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IE, do the following:

Tools menu -> Options -> Advanced tab -> "Browsing" category -> Turn off "Show friendly HTTP error messages".

Close the browser and navigate to your page again. There will probably be an ASP.NET error page waiting for you (assuming you have `customErrors` off). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Cassini running? (just checking)

[http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/2027/casini.jpg http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/2027/casini.jpg](http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/2027/casini.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On the file menu (if using IE 7 or 8, press alt to show the menu) uncheck Work Offline

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your hosts file and TCP/IP settings to make sure you don't have something goofy.

Hosts file (open with Notepad):
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

You should have this line somewhere in the file and localhost shouldn't be associated with any other ip address:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
```

It may also be happening because of AntiVirus or Internet Security software that is installed.

Another suggestion:  Use Firefox, if you go this route, download and play with the firebug extension.

Sorry there isn't anything more I can think of right now, but these were just off the top of my head and the problem you are describing is quite the puzzle...

Answer (score 0):

Like the others say, try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.  I have often had problems with 'localhost' on recent machines because it gets resolved to an IPv6 address, which the client may be delighted with but the server isn't talking.

You can remove the IPv6 mapping for localhost in the hosts file.  (See redbeard's reply)